# CameraRoll React-native

Tags: android, ios, react, react-native

Preciso criar um script que retorne e liste as imagens encontradas na galeria do celular do usuário. Para isso, estou usando o método getPhotos do componente CameraRoll do React-native

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll#getphotos

Tanto no IOS e no Android, o array de imagens são retornadas corretamente. mas quando eu tento usar a **uri** da imagem (usando o componente Image), no IOS ela é exibida, mas no android não.

---

Retorno das imagens no IOS ( **result.edges.node.image.uri** ):

[image: Assets retornados no IOS]

---

Retorno das imagens no Android ( **result.edges.node.image.uri** ):

[image: Assets retornados no Android]

---

Codigo da chamada das imagens:

```
<Image resizeMode="cover" style={[ styles.image_item ]} source={{ uri: image.node.image.uri }} />
```

---

Vesões do React/Expo utilizadas:

[image: Versões do react/expo]

Answer (score 0):

O erro não está na sua prop `styles`? Vi que você passou um array como valor da prop, se não me engano o valor correto é um objeto.

Acho que tirando isso, não tem outro erro. Seu código está praticamente igual ao meu.

```
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: this.state.displayImg.uri,
        }}
        style={{
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          borderRadius: 8,
        }}
      />
```

Comment: A prop style está correta, passei por array pois os estilos estão definidos em outro arquivo. tanto que no IOS as imagens aparecem normalmente.

Imagino que o erro possa estar no valor retornado pelo CameraRoll no Android `content://media/external/images/media/X`

Answer (score 0):

**Tente isso:**

style={styles.image_item}

**Inves de:**

style={[ styles.image_item ]}